# How to disable/enable button based on selection from `Qtableview`

Tags: qt, qtableview, qpushbutton

I have a `QTableView` and a button. When the row is selected from `QTableView` I want button to enable and if the row is not selected then it should disable. can anyone tell how doing it

Answer (score 2):

Use table selection model to handle selection changed signal

then test the selection size.

Example:

```
QItemSelectionModel *poSelectedFiles =
            m_poTableView->selectionModel();

connect(poSelectedFiles,    &QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged,
        this,               &MainWindow::SlotSelectionChanged);


void MainWindow::SlotSelectionChanged(const QItemSelection & oSelected, const QItemSelection & oDeselected)
{    
    const int iSelectedItems  =
            m_poTableView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().size();

    bool bEnabled = (iSelectedItems > 0) ? true : false;
    // Enable button when row is selected.
    ui->poMyButton->setEnabled(bEnabled);
}
```